# problem when I want to import data from one variable to a report

Tags: python, report, odoo

I am trying to make a code which allows importing data that I have in other tables, but I cannot find it, since I have a pre-report sale that one enters the start date and the end date as a range of which I want the data to be made. search and what is between that range I show them in my report but the problem is that in the tables I only have variables called date, so when creating a .search I have to put `('date', '> =', start_date.strftime ( DATETIME_FORMAT))`, and `('date', '<=', end_date.strftime (DATETIME_FORMAT))` so that odoo understands that I want to search for data that is within that range. I also have another question with the docs.append, since the data is taken from the tables but it throws errors due to the bad connection I make, can you please help me. I enclose the code I am making.

```
class Reportledger (models.AbstractModel):

    _name = 'reports.proyecto_rc.ledger_view'

    @ api.model

    def _get_report_values ​​(self, docids, data = None):

        start_date = data ['form'] ['start_date']

        end_date = data ['form'] ['end_date']

        
        docs = []

        document_detail = self.env ['project_rc.detail_document']. search ([

            ('date', '> =', start_date.strftime (DATETIME_FORMAT)),

            ('date', '<=', end_date.strftime (DATETIME_FORMAT)),

            ('title', '=', account.id),

            ('name', '=', company.id),

            ('must', '=', total_debit),

            ('credit', '=', total_credit),

            ])

        
            docs.append ({

                'title': self.detail_document.account_id.titulo,

                'date': detail_document.date,

                'name': self.detail_document.company_id.name,

                'must': detail_document.total_debit,

                'credit': detail_document.total_credit,

            })

        return {

            'doc_ids': data ['ids'],

            'doc_model': data ['model'],

            'start_date': start_date,

            'end_date': end_date,

            'docs': docs,

        }
```

Comment: Hello Francisco González Mejías,Can you posted your error log

Comment: It is a generic error which says that it is an error in project.rc_book but when deleting the doc.append it opens odoo, adding the append does not run and that error appears.